# Display multiple values from two tables in one row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following two tables

```
TableA           Table B

id               bid  bname     btitle
----             ------------------------------
1                1    john      titlejohn
2                1    william   titlewilliam
3                1    george    titlegeorge
                 2    bill      titlebill
                 3    kyle      titlekyle
                 3    seb       titleseb
```

I need a query in SQL Server which displays the following output:

```
id   name                     title
1    john,william,george      titlejohn,titlewilliam,titlegeorgw
2    bill                     titlebill
3    kyle,seb                 titlekyle,titleseb
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  id, name = stuff(n.name, 1, 1, ''), title = stuff(t.title, 1, 1, '')
from    TableA a
    outer apply
    (
        select  ',' + bname
        from    TableB x
        where   x.bid   = a.id
        for xml path('')
    ) n (name)
    outer apply
    (
        select  ',' + btitle
        from    TableB x
        where   x.bid   = a.id
        for xml path('')
    ) t (title)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution. It only handles `bname` but you can extend it to handle `btitle`. Concatenating column values for a given key is not a natural thing in SQL so you need a trick to loop through the table extracting each row with same key. The trick is to create a memory table with an identity column (`n` say) which autoincrements on each insert. You can loop through then, picking n=1, then n=2, etc to build up the string.

```
create function tbl_join_name( @id int)
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @tbl table (n int identity(1,1), name varchar(max), title varchar(max))
    insert @tbl( name, title )
    select bname, btitle from TableB where bid = @id

    declare @n int = 1, @name varchar(max) = '', @count int = (select count(*) from @tbl)
    while @n <= @count begin
        set @name = @name + (case @name when '' then '' else ',' end) + (select name from @tbl where n = @n)
        set @n = @n + 1 
    end
    return @name 
end
go

select id, tbl_join_name(id) as bname --, tbl_join_title(id) as btitle
from TableA
```

It's not very efficient, though. Tested with Sql Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
SELECT  A.id,
        STUFF((SELECT ','+bname
        FROM TableB B
        WHERE B.bid = A.id
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as name,
        STUFF((SELECT ','+btitle
        FROM TableB B
        WHERE B.bid = A.id
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as title
FROM TableA A
```

Output:

```
id  name                title
1   john,william,george titlejohn,titlewilliam,titlegeorge
2   bill                titlebill
3   kyle,seb            titlekyle,titleseb
```